# Error on trying to create HawkConsole Object on TIBCO Hawk JAVA API

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-business-works

When i'm trying to create a HawkConsole Object using Hawk JAVA API, i'm  get bellow error message

> Unable to create EMS transport:
>   COM.TIBCO.hawk.console.nest.shared.TransportInitializationException:
>   COM/TIBCO/hawk/util/security/PasswordObfuscation

I'm using the follow code to try to create the object

```
hawkConsole = new TIBHawkConsole("MyDomain",
                  "MyEMSConnectionString",
                  "MyUserTOEMS",
                  "MyPasswortoEMS",
                  1);
```

In according with the official documentation, to the last parameter can be used anyone number ... This will be ignored ...

The object is successfully created but when the below line is executed the error happens

`getAgentMonitor().initialize;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the exact syntax is `getAgentMonitor():initialize;`

Try to do and told me if it works.

Comment: Hi Ian ... I aprreciate the efforts to help .. but ... my question is not related to syntax ... If you do read carefully the question, the error is in execution time ... and the API is for JAVA and "getAgentMonitor():initialize" is not  a valid syntax for this language. Thank you !!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.
Its necessary add the security.jar and utils.jar extracted from lib Hawk folder, on the Top of BUildPath to work.